# date format in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have the following two names in MySQL table:

`message` is type `text`

`date` is type `datetime`

```
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
     <td><div><a><? echo $row['message'] ?></a></div></td>
     <td><div><a><? echo $row['date']; ?></a></div></td>
</tr>
<?php
 }
?>
```

The output of the above table shows date in this format 2012-08-05 17:43:57

How to print date in this format 2012-08-05 (without time)?

I cannot change type datetime in MySQl (it’s required in different pages in different formats).

I’ve tried the following, but it doesn’t help (no printing at all)

```
<td><div><a><? echo $rows['date'](“Y-m-d”); ?></a></div></td>
```

p.s. other combinations of date format give me syntax error.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['date'])); ?>
```

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) converts your datestring into a unix-timestamp

then, the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function formats it properly according to the string.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `date()` to change the format.

Comment: I don’t want the date to change the time format, I just need echo of date (Y-m-d), without time.

Comment: It's the same function. Read @Erty 's answer. It has a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [format function](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php)

```
echo new DateTime($row['date'])->format('Y-m-d');
```

UPDATED thanks to @Erty

Comment: Don't you need to instantiate a DateTime object first, or is that done automatically?

Comment: You are right @Erty. Its been a long time without php for me :(

Comment: Ok... I thinkg I just should get away in this one... Just by curiosity, why shouldn't this work?

Comment: Because strtotime returns an int, but the ->format() function works on a DateTime object. So you want `new DateTime($row['date'])->format('Y-m-d');`

Comment: +1 for being polite and amicable about the corrections. Keep on learning :D

Answer (score 0):

There is something called TO_CHAR method in MS-SQL and Oracle in which you can pass the format you want your date in,  so while fetching the data you can change it

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

```
 <td><div><a><? echo new DateTime($row['date'])->format('Y-m-d'); ; ?></a></div></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to convert it to a date:

```
$tmpdate = strtotime($row['date']);
$date = date('Y-M-d', $tmpdate);
echo $date;
```

Of course you may short it down, as others suggested, but i prefer "the long way" to improve readability and help you get up to speed faster when you go back and review old code in the future. :-)

Comment: Thanks but I receive syntax error 
Notice: Use of undefined constant date - assumed 'date' in C:\xampp\htdocs\MySQLprtnr\getlisting.php on line 128

Answer (score 0):

every one else is suggesting you do it with php, i always do this with mySQL's own date function:

```
SELECT ... DATE_FORMAT(Date_Field ,'%Y-%e-%c') ...
```

[DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)